# How to bevel an extruded Bézier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

[image]

I have a curved extruded object (see below) which I want to add a shallow gradual bevel to so its like a pyramid effect. How can I achieve this?
Item is to be 3D printed so it needs high resolution vertices for smooth curves.

This is a medallion, so it needs a flat surface gradually raising to emblem.

Adding a bevel breaks instantly as the end points meet very early on.
I tried extruding new layers each scaled down but the shape doesn't allow for that to work.
What else can I do other than literally drawing stacked shapes..?

I created the object by doing the following:

- Add Bezier Curve
- Bezier Curve Modifier (Resolution: 40)
- *Object > Convert > Mesh*
- Edit Mode - Select All Points - <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face
- Extrude Up

[image]

Comment: hello do you have a reference image of what you want?

Comment: Added an image to original post as a rough guide to what I want, does this help?

Comment: so is it different from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Activate the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*, select the top face and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Move*:

[image]

Then in the *Operator Box* change the *Width* value:

[image]

In your case I'm not sure that there's any automatic and quick way to do it, maybe first select all the edge ring and checker deselect (set the selection ratio in the *Operator Box*):

[image]

Then dissolve. Also dissolve the edges that are too close to the peaks:

[image]

Offset, it will give something a bit messy:

[image]

Correct manually:

[image]

Bevel the edges that you want to keep sharp:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to add topology (you'll need to create additional edges on the top):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thats very close.
Only thing is it creates big crossoverss straight away similar to the bezel modifier, not sure how to stop this.

https://imgur.com/a/OiqYW23

Comment: there are a lot of vertical edges, you should simplify, for example with the Checker Deselect trick, but maybe share your file, you can use https://blendertribu.forumactif.com/

Comment: @Fred_was_here **Re:** *"not sure how to stop this"* Do as moonboots suggested **-or-** fix it *after* doing the Offset Edges operation, by [Merging](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/merge.html) verts, or (if you need to preserve the topology) by doing [Edge Slide](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_slide.html) operations to space the vertices apart. The more extreme your offset is, the more sacrifices you will need to make, using some combination of the aforementioned methods.

Comment: And just to clarify, "the more extreme your offset is..." *means*: the more acute the inner angles are, and the further the distance is that you are offsetting.

Comment: @moonbots I am 3D printing this as a jewellery piece so need to retain high resolution and ultra smooth edges, if I reduce the verticals I will get straight edges won't i?

Please let me also point out, Iam very much a beginner with Blender.

I have included my file here
https://www.filesharesite.com/files/202306/16859602061BA61848C6841893AA21E7249785BA16.html

Comment: I've edited my answer, for your shape you'll need to give some manual correction once you've simplified and offset

Comment: @moonboots Thanks thats working well for me now!  
One question, after I have applied the 'edge-move' and clicked off that window, how do I bring that edit panel back up?

Comment: @Mentalist Thank you.

Comment: You can click F9, but if you do another action, it won't be availabla anymore